# Is it a photodiode or a phototransistor?

Tags: pcb, photodiode, phototransistor

I have been working on a circuit which involves a photosensitive element soldered on a PCB. I am confused whether it is a photodiode or a phototransistor.

Is there any means by which I can figure out whether its a photodiode or phototransistor without desoldering it?

It is a two terminal device.
Picture of device:

[image]

Comment: Shine light on it and see if current comes out?

Comment: If you are working on this circuit then please give part numbers of the device.

Comment: What is the device? An safety device for a punch press?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few ways you can do this:

1. Connect a voltmeter across the leads and shine a bright light or a laser pointer on it. If the voltmeter reads a voltage (not just noise) then it is probably a photodiode.
2. Connect a diode tester across the leads. While this isn't ideal as they are in-circuit, it may still work. If your diode tester doesn't read anything, swap the leads around. If you still don't see a reading, then it's probably a phototransistor.
3. If the board has some sort of amplifier (an op-amp, most likely) connected close to these devices, they're probably photodiodes. Otherwise they could be phototransistors, which are just switches and wouldn't need amplification.
4. Do the PCB designators show a "D" or a "Q"? "D" is for diode, "Q" is for transistor

In order to get a more accurate reading (particularly with the diode test) it would be best to desolder one leg of the device (to take it out of the circuit) before measuring. However, it looks like there is some sort of gunk holding it to the board so you may need to remove that first.

Obviously a better view of the (entire) board and part numbers would be very helpful in this case.

Comment: thanks a lot for the help. I have figured out that its a photodiode.

Comment: Now I am facing another problem.I believe that the connecting circuit, consisting a BJT, must work as an amplifier circuit. I expect it to be something like ![this](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-TvnXuouhLDZ05YTmw2SGlJNEE&authuser=0).
However, on reverse engineering, the actual circuit turns out to be something like ![this](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-TvnXuouhLDaHl3V1Rtd2hRZmM&authuser=0).I am confused whether I am thinking in the right direction or not. Please help @derstrom8

Comment: That schematic doesn't seem to make much sense. What type of transistor is it (do you have a part number)? Seeing as the emitter is connected to Vcc, I am wondering if it is a PNP?

Comment: Also, I don't think you ever answered, what is this circuit used for? It might help us figure out what it is doing

Comment: Yes, it is a PNP transistor, its part no. is [BC857](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/BC856_BC857_BC858.pdf). I expect it to be a common emitter config. of an amplifier but since the emitter is connected to Vcc, i dont think it would be a common emitter config. what do you say?

Comment: sorry i missed answering you the use of this circuit. It works as a laser receiver circuit.

Comment: Well of course it's a receiver circuit, but what's it for?

Comment: Also, what does it mean by "To similar circuit"? Where does that connect on the "similar circuit"? I have redrawn the schematic you drew and it actually looks fairly reasonable for a PNP circuit. The transistor will conduct when there is 0V on the base. The capacitor will block any DC coming from the photodiode, so I expect this is designed to reject constant lighting.

Comment: Its a Receiver for laser leveller. There are three photodiodes circuits(similar to the one i drew) connected together at the common "To similar circuit" point. This point is then connected to the inverting input of an Op amp. can you please send me the redrawn circuit alongwith a brief explanation at danendra.singh10@gmail.com

Comment: i tried to simulate the circuit using an online simulator where i am taking output across collector. Unfortunately the output is not showing any amplification

Comment: If it is connected to an op-amp then it's likely not intended to be an amplifier. It could just be used (with the other circuitry) to reject any DC (to prevent the circuit from latching "ON"). The transistor is probably used like this to prevent ordinary sunlight (or ambient light) from affecting the circuit--only fast pulsing light (i.e. the laser, with the high pass filter frequency being determined by the capacitor values) can pass through to the output. The op-amp will be doing your amplification or signal forming.

Comment: Here is the redrawing of your schematic. I apologize for the crudity, I just threw it together. The diode shown is actually the photodiode: http://s21.postimg.org/hmq66wj6v/2015_06_19_09_17_22_1_Schematic_C_EAGLE_7_3_0.png

Comment: thanks for the info. So you mean that the function of the transistor is to act as a switch? [here's](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-TvnXuouhLDYjRXVnMyOEM4V2p5dmp0WllEWnFIZ210ZEU4&authuser=0) the complete circuit with the op amp. what do you think of this?

Comment: That's a much different circuit from the one you showed before. And please take note that PNP transistors (which you said are used in the circuit) are drawn differently than NPN transistors. You keep drawing NPNs, not PNPs. But yes, I expect the transistors are acting as a switch in this case

Answer (score 1):

Just from the looks of the active area, it certainly looks like a photodiode.

However, since it's a 2-lead device, it doesn't matter which it is - it will be used the same way in either case. The difference between the two is generally that photodiodes are faster but less sensitive, while phototransistors are more sensitive but slower. Phototransistors also have greater dark current. In any case, each is used in a circuit which converts photocurrent to voltage. In the case of a phototransistor, this is usually a simple resistor, while photodiodes (with their lower currents) ordinarily use some sort of amplifier.

As I say, the large active area which is visible says they are probably photodiodes.

Comment: That would be my guess, I've never seen a photo transistor with such a big active area.  (I wouldn't say that a phototransistor is more sensitive than a photo diode... one photon makes one e-h pair, the photo transistor just has built in gain.  but maybe that is only semantics.)